# Why do windows change in pixel size when dragged between monitors with the same resolution? (Lenovo with Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

video:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByLdHbPnpVjWSjU3cjc1d29tUlU/edit?usp=sharing

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Z50-70 laptop; it's connected to a samsung monitor in a dual monitor setup. When I drag any window between the two monitors it changes it's scales in pixel size and expands when it reaches the laptop monitor.

For instance, if I take a screenshot of a website on the Samsung, the images will be in their original size, a 500x500 image will be 500x500 in the screenshot. If I drag it to the Lenovo monitor and take a screen, it takes 25% more space i.e 600x600.

It is as if I pressed `ctrl +` several times to scale it up. The same thing happens when I drag a `cmd` window. It looks correct on the Samsung and gets enlarged when I move it to the laptop.

It is important to state and **emphasize** both monitors are running at the same 1920*1080.
And that I am not talking about their appearance. I am talking about their size in pixels.

I tried hitting `ctrl 0` to scale the window to the default resolution. It did not change anything.

Here is a sluggish video showing how the window changes in it's pixel size when dragged up and down between the two monitors:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByLdHbPnpVjWSjU3cjc1d29tUlU/edit?usp=sharing

Here is a screen shot of my resolution settings:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can actually see the window change in size when I drag it from one monitor to another. I don't mean the DPI which is obvious.. I mean the number of pixels.

Comment: @Twisty - It is Windows 8.1 to be specific. It's interrupting my work cause a lot of it involves pixel perfect precision and if my monitor is enlarging the image unexpectedly I get a wrong reading of the actual size in pixels when I take a screenshot for instance.

Comment: I'm finding that in Windows 10, each monitor already has its own scale setting. Monitor 1 = 200%, Monitors 2 & 3 have 100%. My problem is that certain apps (Skype for Business specifically) dragged from 1 to 2 or 3 keep the 200% scale from 1 regardless of the scale setting. Seems a known issue on uservoice. http://www.skypefeedback.com/forums/299913-generally-available/suggestions/9572103-skype-for-business-in-latest-2016-preview-still-no#comments

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disable Windows 8's scaling.

To do this, go to **Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Display** and select the **Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays** option. Then, select the **Smaller - 100%** option.

Comment: I don't know if Windows changed it in an update since mid-2014 or if my Intel graphics driver is mangling the "pure" experience, but on my 8.1 machine I had to do "Display" > "Screen Resolution" > "Make text and other items larger or smaller" to get to the scaling settings.  Still, this answer got me in the ballpark so I could solve my own problem, so +1.